# Nested forms rails 3 strong parameters AGAIN

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested, models

I am trying to do nested forms.

I have Project with many Items

I have the code at:

https://github.com/brylor/rails-super-project-management

Summary:

I have a

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

... in the project controller

@project.items.build  in the new and edit actions,

along with strong parameters in the projects controller:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:title, :content, items_attributes: [:title, :content,:project_id])
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what is not working. :) - Never mind, found it.

Comment: please mention if any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

And again, it's a typo. :)

`app/views/projects/_form.html.erb`, line 23:

```
<%= f.fields_for :item do |p| %>
```

Your association is called `items`, not `item`.